# Send a POST method using a CSV as form-data Karate Framework

Tags: csv, post, request, multipartform-data, karate

I need to implement this request in Karate:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https:/myURL/' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer myToken' \
--form 'csv=@"newUser.csv"'
```

PS: newUser.csv file is in the same folder as my feature

This is how I am sending my request on Postman:

[Postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfvcL.png)

I tried this:

```
Scenario: Bulk New Users - csv file with 1 user
  Given header Authorization = accessToken
  And multipart field csv = { read: 'newUser.csv', contentType: 'multipart/form-data' }
  When method post
  Then status 202
```

But getting 400

I also tried this:

```
Scenario: Bulk New Users - csv file with 1 user
  Given header Authorization = accessToken
  And form field csv = { read: 'newUser.csv' }
  When method post
  Then status 202
```

And it's like I'm not sending anything

Finally, if I try this:

```
Scenario: Bulk New Users - csv file with 1 user
  Given header Authorization = accessToken
  And multipart file csv = { read: 'classpath:newUser.csv'}
  When method post
  Then status 202
```

Getting: "could not find or read file: classpath:newUser.csv"

Don't know what I am doing wrong here, I see a lot of examples on internet, none of them worked for me, appreciatte your help on this. thanks in advance

EDIT:

I tried the solution given by Peter but now, I am getting a message from my service that only CSV files are allowed:

[image: Error message]

Which will be the case when I not attached the csv file or use a file with different extension:

[image: Postman]

And this is how it looks the request on Karate logs:

[image: Postman]

It seems I am not sending anything as a body after the conversion to string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this change:

```
* def fileContents = karate.readAsString('classpath:newUser.csv')
* multipart file csv = { value: '#(fileContents)' }
```

Refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#csv-files

Comment: Hi Peter, I appreciatte your fast anwser on this, but if I do that, my service is telling me only CSV files are allowed, at least now its taking the csv form parameter correctly but it seems like I am not sending any file

Comment: @EstebanManosalva then just add a `contentType: 'text/csv'` or whatever your server is expecting. I'm sorry because multipart questions are terribly hard to answer unless you can replicate it. so my suggestion is please read this if the above does not work and I wish you all the best: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1645#issuecomment-862502881

Comment: @EstebanManosalva also add a `filename: 'somename.csv'` so that the server sees a file with extension `.csv`. refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#multipart-file

Comment: Thanks man! It worked! Finally, adding contentType and filename solved the issue.

Comment: @EstebanManosalva that is great to know. thanks for accepting the answer, and this thread will help others